# Identities about $p$-th root of unity

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I found a simple formula for the following sequence
$$
a(p) = \sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}(-1)^{n}\zeta_{p}^{(n+\frac{25-p^{2}}{24})j}(1-\zeta_{p}^{j})\cdots(1-\zeta_{p}^{nj})
$$
where $p\geq 5$ is a prime. For example, we have
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{6}\sum_{n=0}^{6}(-1)^{n}\zeta_{7}^{(n-1)j}(1-\zeta_{7}^{j})\cdots (1-\zeta_{7}^{nj}) = -14
$$
and
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{72}\sum_{n=0}^{72}(-1)^{n}\zeta_{73}^{(n-222)j}(1-\zeta_{73}^{j})\cdots (1-\zeta_{73}^{nj}) = 146.
$$
Are these formulas known? I also checked that these formulas are right by MATLAB.